# WSL2 : apt-get install/remove are not working

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Whenever I try to install or remove a packet with apt, I get this error :

```
E: Could not read response to hello message from hook [ ! -f /usr/bin/snap ] || /usr/bin/snap advise-snap --from-apt 2>/dev/null || true: Success
```

I believe this started when I installed then uninstalled snap (via apt), but I'm not sure. Could you explain what this means, and how to solve this issue please ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
```

Probably some leftover configuration for snap is triggering this error message. The command above should clear it up.

Comment: I suggest to remove the `-r` option because you want to remove a single file only. `rm -rf ...` might be dangerous in case you have an error/typo in the argument, and even more dangerous in combination with `sudo`.

Comment: I works ! Thank you !